# Dropdown not selecting value in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am unable to open dropdown and select value from that

The first value is "Please select" but I am unable to select another value.

I tried this one but its not working.

```
WebElement element3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@placeholder='Property Type']/preceding-sibling::input[@value='Please Select']")); 
element3.click(); 
Select element4 = new Select(element3); 
element4.selectByValue("8");
```

Comment: Please add your code, so we can understand your problem

Comment: WebElement element3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@placeholder='Property Type']/preceding-sibling::input[@value='Please Select']")); 
element3.click();
Select element4 = new Select(element3);
element4.selectByValue("8");

Comment: This is code opening dropdown but unable to select value

Comment: can you share the html code?

Comment: @kavya ... what i'm getting here `element3.click();` not working for you...try `WebElement element3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@placeholder='Property Type']/preceding-sibling::input[@value='Please Select']")); element3.click(); element3.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN + Keys.ENTER);` ...hope this should work for you.

Comment: @kavya ..kindly ignore my previous comment..try this 
`WebElement element3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@placeholder='Property Type']/preceding-sibling::input[@value='Please Select']")); Select element4 = new Select(element3); element4.selectByValue("8");` ...hope this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The "value" is not always what you would think it is.  Without seeing the HTML code behind the Select I can't be sure, but what you are likely looking for is:

```
element4.selectByVisibleText("8");
```

Alternatively, if you know the index number you could:

```
element4.selectByIndex(index);
```